# Changing the favicon not reflecting on the site

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5, dxa-net

I have tried to change the favicon for my site by following the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-81F0EF8D-8134-4260-A17B-F7A0D8FEF939), but it is not reflecting. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After changing DXA configuration, like the HTML Design or items of it, you will always need to refresh the cache of the application, so it will load the updated configuration (from which the favicon is one).

So start with calling the Admin controller refresh route (`/admin/refresh`) and then there might still be the issue of the browser caching the old favicon, that mostly can be resolved by requesting the favicon itself directly (`/favicon.ico`) and pressing [Ctrl] + [F5].